# Image converter java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

i'm working with image processing, and i have a question.

I want read an image from project, and convert the image to gray.
I'm currently trying to do conversion with the function rgb2gray, but still not working.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ImageTesting extends Component {
    private static int[] pixel;
    private static BufferedImage b;

    BufferedImage image;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public ImageTesting() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("teste.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (image == null) {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        } else {
            return new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
        }
    }

    public static BufferedImage rgb2gray(BufferedImage bi) {
        int heightLimit = bi.getHeight();
        int widthLimit = bi.getTileWidth();
        BufferedImage converted = new BufferedImage(widthLimit, heightLimit, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        for (int height = 0; height < heightLimit; height++) {
            for (int width = 0; width < widthLimit; width++) {
                Color c = new Color(bi.getRGB(width, height) & 0x00fffff);
                int newRed = (int) ((0.2989f * c.getRed()) * 2);// 0.2989f//multiplicr po 2
                int newGreen = (int) ((0.5870f * c.getGreen()) * 2);// 0.5870f
                int newBlue = (int) ((0.1140f * c.getBlue()) * 2);
                int roOffset = newRed + newGreen + newBlue;
                converted.setRGB(width, height, roOffset);
            }
        }
        return converted;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");
        JFrame g = new JFrame("Image RGB");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        g.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        f.add(new ImageTesting());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        g.add(new ImageTesting());
        rgb2gray(b);
    }
}
```

When I run the program,these are the errors that appear.

If anyone could help me, i apreciate.
Thanks

**Edit:**
I managed to solve this problem,but now another question came up. To continue my work, i want to find the most 10 brilhants points in the resultant image, and return another image with black color in the index's that have the value 0, and white color in the index's that have value 1,but at this point i don't understand the best way to work out the steps.

Comment: *"i have a doubt"*  Save your doubts for the claims of used car salesmen and politicians.  If you have a question, ask it (& call it a question).  What is your question?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I would save the criticisms about choice of words. It's quite possible the OP is not a native English speaker and perhaps doesn't realise "I have a doubt" is an unusual phrase to use.

Comment: "these are the errors that appear" - Did you forget to post the errors? Edit your post, add the error messages. That makes it so much easier to help you fix them.

Comment: @DuncanJones *"It's quite possible the OP is not a native English speaker"*  Quite true, and to get best help from other people who speak English as a 2nd (..3rd whatever) language, it pays to stick to the most common form of the language.  That usage is used *only* by people from India.

Comment: I edited my question with a new question about the same code.

Comment: did you have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImageOp.html?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's something wrong with the main() method, isn't it? You create two completely identical JFrame instances, then add Imagetesting components that display the original image. And when running rgb2gray at the end, the result is sent nowhere.

Comment: These errors are:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at imagetesting.ImageTesting.rgb2gray(ImageTesting.java:52)
 at imagetesting.ImageTesting.main(ImageTesting.java:91)

Comment: Dmitriy, i managed to solve this problem.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using image filters, see related documentation here: http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/

It's performant and simple to use.